# Smooth proper schemes over Z with points everywhere locally

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, open-problems

This is a variation on [Poonen's question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9576/smooth-proper-scheme-over-z), taking [Buzzard's fabulous example](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9576/smooth-proper-scheme-over-z/9605#9605) into account.  It was earlier a part of [this other question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10569/smooth-proper-schemes-over-z-with-points-everywhere-locally).

**Question.**  *Is there a smooth proper scheme* $X\to\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ *such that* $X(\mathbb{Q}_v)\neq\emptyset$ *for every place* $v$ *of* $\ \mathbb{Q}$ (*including* $v=\infty$), *and yet* $X(\mathbb{Q})=\emptyset$ ?

I believe the answer is No.  The evidence is flimsy : $X$ cannot be a curve or a torsor under an abelian variety (Abrashkin-Fontaine) or a twisted form of $\mathbb{P}_n$.

I haven't gone through a list of smooth projective $\mathbb{Q}$-varieties which contradict  the Hasse principle to check if any of them has good reduction everywhere, but the chances of such a thing are slim.

[Colliot-Thélène and Xu](http://www.math.u-psud.fr/~colliot/CTXuCompositio2009.pdf) give a systematic treatement of many known examples of *quasi-projective* $\mathbb{Z}$-schemes $Y$ such that $Y(\mathbb{Z}_p)\neq\emptyset$ for every prime $p$ and $Y(\mathbb{R})\neq\emptyset$, but $Y(\mathbb{Z})=\emptyset$. Some of these schemes might even be smooth over $\mathbb{Z}$, but none of them is proper.

[Fontaine's letter to Messing](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=fontaine&s5=&s6=&s7=indo-french&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=2&mx-pid=1274493) (MR1274493) might be of some relevance here.