# Are there smooth and proper schemes over $\mathbb Z$ whose cohomology is not of Tate type

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, cohomology

> Is there an example of smooth and proper *scheme* $X \to \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb Z)$, and an integer $i$ such that $H^i(X, \mathbb Q)$ is *not* a Hodge structure of Tate type?
>   Alternatively: such that $H^i(X_{\bar{\mathbb{Q}}}, \mathbb{Q}_\ell)$ is not a Galois representation of Tate type?

- A result of Fontaine says that $H^q(X,\Omega^p) = 0$ if $p \ne q$, and $p+q \le 3$.
  So we need $\dim(X) > 3$.
- If we allow stacks, then examples come from the theory of modular forms: $H^{11}(\bar{M}_{1,11})$ is associated with the Ramanujan $\Delta$ function. So this question is explicitly about *schemes*.

An explicit example would be wonderful. An inexplicit proof that such an $X$ exists is fine as well.

---

Related questions:

- [Does smooth and proper over $\mathbb Z$ imply rational?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/97086/does-smooth-and-proper-over-mathbb-z-imply-rational)
- [Smooth proper schemes over Z with points everywhere locally](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11316/smooth-proper-schemes-over-z-with-points-everywhere-locally)
- [Smooth proper scheme over Z](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9576/smooth-proper-scheme-over-z)
- [What can be the dimension of a pointless smooth proper Z-scheme?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111708/what-can-be-the-dimension-of-a-pointless-smooth-proper-z-scheme)

Comment: Doesn't the result of Fontaine need $p \neq q$?

Comment: @TimoKeller: Oo, yes of course.

Comment: I think I calculated once that under GRH, Fontaine's argument goes through for $p+q \leq 4$. So one needs dimension at least 5. However, there is no real hope I see of doing this in any dimension $<11$. One approach would be to try to resolve the singularities of the coarse moduli space of $\overline{\mathcal M}_{1,11}$. Taking the Hilbert scheme might be a good first step, as this resolves some singularities in coarse moduli spaces of quotient stacks.

Comment: This is a notorious open problem.  As Will says, there are natural examples of smooth proper DM *stacks* with interesting cohomology (e.g. $\overline{\mathcal{M}_{g,n}}$).  But there is no known scheme example.

Comment: @DanielLitt: Yes, I am aware of those natural examples (see the question, where I mention $\overline{M}_{1,11}$). One line of attack that I was thinking about for a proof of *existence* was to use general results about categories of motives built from smooth projective varieties versus motives built from smooth proper DM stacks. I think that over fields there are theorem that say they give the same category. I don't know if something like this also works over $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @WillSawin: Ok, that is good to know. I don't expect *explicit* examples with dimension $< 11$. But even an explicit example with dimension $\ge 11$ does not seem trivial.

Comment: @user114562 I don't think this could work because the reduction passes through possibly singular schemes, and you need alteration or resolution to get back to smooth schemes, neither of which work over $\mathbb Z$.  Essentially your problem is just a big Diophantine equation, and there is very rarely a nonconstructive existence proof for solutions to a Diophantine equation.

Comment: Chenevier and Lannes have pursued the automorphic approach (initiated by Mestre and Fermigier) to this question, generalizing the Weil explicit formula. Namely, they classify the algebraic cuspidal representations of $\mathrm{PGL}_n$ of motivic weight $\leq 22$ and show that the belong to an explicit list of $11$ representations. In their list, only the trivial representation has motivic weight $<11$ and corresponds to Ramanujan's $\Delta$.

Comment: @ACL: Right, so that suggest that there definitely shouldn't be anything with dim $< 11$. Do some Langlands-type conjectures imply that there should be smooth proper schemes over $\mathbb Z$ with non-Tate cohomology? Or is it expected that we *need* to include DM-stacks to get all the motives that appear in the Chenevier-Lannes list?

Comment: Is it any different if you just ask that $X$ has good reduction everywhere, i.e. for every $p$ there exists a smooth proper model $\mathscr X_p \to \operatorname{Spec} \mathbf Z_{(p)}$ (but the model is allowed to depend on $p$)?